# EBS Custom.pll Validation on HRMS Position Window on Duplicate Insert and update of Position and Location

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

```
  procedure event(event_name varchar2) is 

form_name        VARCHAR2 (30)   := NAME_IN ('system.current_form');
   block_name       VARCHAR2 (30)   := NAME_IN ('system.cursor_block');
   item_name        VARCHAR2 (100)  := NAME_IN ('system.current_item');

  BEGIN   

 If  (  (event_name='PRE-UPDATE') or (EVENT_NAME = 'WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD'   ) ) and 
           form_name ='HRWSPSF'  and block_name ='POSITIONS' and item_name IN ('SEGMENT1','SEGMENT2','SEGMENT3','LOCATION_ID')
           and   NAME_IN('SYSTEM.RECORD_STATUS')IN ('CHANGED') 
           then     
         DECLARE
                L_SEGMENT    NUMBER;
            L_POS       NUMBER;
                P_SEGMENT1 VARCHAR2(255):=NAME_IN('POSITIONS.SEGMENT1');
                P_SEGMENT2 VARCHAR2(255):=NAME_IN('POSITIONS.SEGMENT2');
                P_SEGMENT3 VARCHAR2(255):=NAME_IN('POSITIONS.SEGMENT3');
                P_LOCATION_ID NUMBER:=NAME_IN('POSITIONS.LOCATION_ID');
         BEGIN

                  SELECT count(*) into L_SEGMENT
                FROM  hr_all_positions_f hapf,
                per_position_definitions ppd
                WHERE hapf.position_definition_id = ppd.position_definition_id
                AND PPD.SEGMENT1 = P_SEGMENT1
                AND PPD.SEGMENT2=P_SEGMENT2
                AND hapf.business_group_id = 111
                AND HAPF.LOCATION_ID = P_LOCATION_ID;

           IF (L_SEGMENT>=1) THEN
            FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('PER','IGFMIS_DUPLICATE_POSITION');
                  FND_MESSAGE.error;
              RAISE form_trigger_failure;
           END IF;

                SELECT count(*) into L_POS
                FROM per_position_definitions ppd
                WHERE PPD.SEGMENT3 = P_SEGMENT3;

         IF (L_POS>=1) THEN
           FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('PER','IGFMIS_DUPLICATE_POSITION_CODE');
                  FND_MESSAGE.error;
              RAISE form_trigger_failure;
         END IF;

         END;
         END IF;
end event;
```

It is not working.Validation should be on insert and update of position and location field.I think IF condition is not working .Need to know the proper IF condition. How to validate only for some particular field .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know EBS, but your checked event names are same as Oracle Forms triggers.

`PRE-UPDATE` trigger fires before program updates record in database as part of commit form process. It fires after user commits data by pressing F10 for example.

`WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD` trigger fires after user "leaves the record". It means when user moves to other record or block. It also fires after user commits data. It does not fire when user moves between items (fields) in same record.

If you need to validate an item after user leaves it, use `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM`. Maybe it works in EBS too.

Comment: @Petr-Thanks a lot.Oracle EBS have the same forms as Oracle forms.I have tried using WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM but in that case also it is validating for every item or field of a form.I need to know how to apply validation only on one or two items of a block after saving or commiting.

Comment: Check item_name variable. If it contains your item name, do the rest of code. Item name is stored like 'YOUR_BLOCK.YOUR_ITEM'